# Docker image and docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I pushed and pulled back an image that contains a dockerfile and a docker-compose.
After pulling I ran `docker run` and the container correctly starts but I see that all settings made in docker compose file are ignored. I there a way to invoke the docker-compose file inside the image that I pulled?

Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache maven
VOLUME /tmp
ADD . .
ADD /target/demoCI-CD-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
 web:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "80:8080"
```

Comment: The image does not contain the Compose setup.  You could run the image in a different Compose setup, or as you're doing without Compose involved at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the docker-compose file you have to use the `docker compose up` command (or `docker-compose up` depending on your version)

Might want to take a look at
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Comment: So I can docker compose up 'containersha' ? Can the dockercompose.yaml be located inside the container?

Comment: I think you need to spend the time to read the documentation or the getting started page. The docker-compose.yml file has to be next to your dockerfile because that's the path you set in your yml. Docker compose up will read the yml file in the current directory and start all containers listed in it. You don't need any param. No it can't be inside the container, it's with that file that you'll start the container.